# TFS 2013 Dependent Assembly XXX of XXX not found when building solution

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit, .net-assembly

When building my project in TFS 2013 I get these warnings which says that some assemblies are not found in my test projects, and that they can be ignored. Looking on the server where the build is, the assemblies are there. All the tests pass just fine.

I have tried to search this up, but most of the answers are related to `TestCategory`. I do not use `TestCategories` in my tests, so all of these answers are bit far from my situation.

How can I get rid of these warnings?

Snapshot of the warnings here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First I would try removing the references to these assemblies if they aren't needed.

If you find they are needed:

The first DLL (NServiceBus.Core) is referenced from a Nuget package.  Make sure to included this Nuget package into source control or enable the Restore Nuget package option.

The others are all referenced from the `obj` folders of other projects.  You should reference them from a Nuget package instead.